# equal hamming distance (or scalar product) between all pairs

Tags: linear-algebra

am I'm searching for an algorithm which constructs a set of **different binary vectors/strings** with the property, that each vector-pair has the same hamming distance (or in other words "the same scalar product").

The Algorithm gets as input only the number **n**, which is the number of needed vectors. The goal is not only to construct this set but also to keep the **bitsize of the vectors as low as possible** (asymptotically).

Examples:

equal_hamming_distance(2):
{01}
{10}

equal_hamming_distance(3):
{100}
{010}
{001}

equal_hamming_distance(4):
{1000}
{0100}
{0010}
{0001}

The above example is trivial. Each pair has the **scalar product 0** and the **bitsize is O(n)** which is very bad.

My questions:

- Is there an algorithm which constructs for a given n a set with vectors of bitsize smaller than n? (The scalar product does have to be zero, it may be any value)
- Is there a known lower bound for the bitsize?

Edit 1: I just realized, that "hamming distance" and "scalar product" may not have the same results. I am interested in both.

Edit 2: After thinking a bit I came to the conclusion, that using a "scalar product" it is not possible to beat O(n), because the "n+1" vector is linear dependant on the n previous vectors.

Thank you

Comment: One potential motivation: Rows of a $4n\times4n$ [Hadamard matrix](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/mcs425-s08/handouts/Hadamard_codes.pdf) have equal pair-wise hamming distances, which is equal to half the matrix's order, $2n$.

Comment: Hamming distance and Scalar Product are fundamentally incompatible mathematical concepts. If, for example, you consider the number field $\mathbb R$ (to define the Scalar product) you do not have a meaningful definition of Hamming distance. If, on the other Hand, you consider a finite field you are missing the Scalar product.